# 2009 Impala LT Airbag code B0014-0D

Tags: supplemental-restraint-system, impala

My Impala was intermittently, and now pretty much constantly, giving me a "Service airbags" message.  I hooked it up to an Innova 3150f and it gave me: "B0014-0D: Driver Seat Side Air Bag Deployment Loop - High Resistance"  Is there anything I can try to do to remedy this myself without significant risk of deploying the airbags?

Answer (score 1):

Seems there's an [issue](https://gm.oemdtc.com/tag/b0014) for 2016 Volts with the the wiring harness getting sliced on the seat frame. Possibly you have something similar going on? Check the seat wiring harness. Trace the wires and inspect for damage. I guess it makes sense that a damaged wire would have increased resistance.